# Can't figure out why graph is not updating

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm setting up a plotly-dash website where I want to show data from some domains from different points in time. Therefore I have a slider with which you can decide which data from which point in time you want to see. That already works. Moreover I want that if somebody clicks on one point it shows a line between all positions of this domain from every point in time.

I have tried to define an update function, so that I update the data for the trace with the line in it. However the graph itself does not look different after the update.

```
# create underlying figure
fig = go.Figure()
for date in file.date.unique():
    f = file.loc[file["date"] == date]

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = f.x,
                         y = f.y,
                         mode="markers",
                         name = date,
                         hovertext = f.domains,
                         visible = False,
                         marker=dict(
                             color=['#a3a7e4'] * len(f.x),
                             size=[5] * len(f.x)
                         ),
                        ))

# trace of path
dom="xxx"
filt = file.loc[file["domains"] == dom]
x_ = filt.x
y_ = filt.y

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter( 
    x = x_,
    y = y_,
    hovertext= dom,
    name='"'+ dom +'"' + " development path",
    visible=True,
    mode='lines'
    ))

# Create and add slider
steps = []
for i in range(len(fig.data)-1):
    step = dict(
        method="restyle",
        args=["visible", [False] * len(fig.data)],
        label=fig.data[i].name
    )
    step["args"][1][i] = True  # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=10,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Date: "},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps
)]
# create widget from figure
f = go.FigureWidget(data=fig.data, layout=fig.layout)

# create our callback function
def update_point(trace, points, selector):

filter_2 = file[(file["x"] == points.xs[0]) & (file["y"] == 
    points.ys[0])]
domain = filter_2.domains.values[0]
print(domain)
small_df = file[file["domains"] == domain]
fig.data[-1].hovertext = domain
fig.data[-1].name = '"' + domain + '"' + " development path"
fig.data[-1].x = small_df.x.values
fig.data[-1].y = small_df.y.values
fig.update_traces(visible=True, selector=dict(mode="line"))
f = go.FigureWidget(data=fig.data, layout=fig.layout)
f


for i in range(len(fig.data)-1):
    if f.data[i].visible is True:
        f.data[i].on_click(update_point)

f
```

I just want the graph to be updated as well, not just the underlying data.

Comment: could you upload a toy data & a stand-alone code, it helps to understand the problem more easily

Comment: Did the answer solve your query? If yes, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Dash callbacks here:

https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started-part-2

In short, you need to add decorators to your callbacks which says which input triggers the callback and which graph needs to be updated on a callback run. You cannot trigger a callback programmatically and expect it to change the graph. The callback needs to come from the UI, as far as I know.

Eg:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='my-id', value='initial value', type='text'),
    html.Div(id='my-div')
])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-div', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='my-id', component_property='value')]
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    return 'You have entered "{}"'.format(input_value)
```

This example expects the callback to be triggered when the input with id "my-id" has a change in value, and in return, it changes the value of the div. The "Output" in the decorator needs to be your graph if you need a callback to change a graph.